# Crash maybe related to webview and chrome - signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview

I have a crash happening at a few customers.

I have a couple of webview and the crash looks like related to chrome.

I see some bugs at bugs.chromium.org but I'm not sure how to handle this one?

I only have this stack trace:

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000071270c  /data/app/com.android.chrome-tF0yaJlYWnkgtHxT7MAlzg==/base.apk
  #01  pc 00000000007124ec  /data/app/com.android.chrome-tF0yaJlYWnkgtHxT7MAlzg==/base.apk
```

Comment: What ads SDKs do you use, if any?